# R script to download all Springer books released for free during the 2020 COVID-19 quarantine

Tags: r

I'm trying to download Springer books available for free, using the following code:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("renanxcortes/springerQuarantineBooksR")

library(springerQuarantineBooksR)

setwd("/Users/fabiano/Desktop/e-books") 
download_springer_book_files(parallel = TRUE)
```

But I'm having the following error:

*Error in download_springer_book_files(parallel = TRUE):
unused argument (parallel = TRUE)*

Comment: seems to work, when you drop the ```parallel = TRUE``` argument

Comment: Error in stringr::str_replace_all(str = string, pattern = replace) :                                                           
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/stringi/R/stringi.rdb' is corrupt
Além disso: Warning messages:
1: In stringr::str_replace_all(str = string, pattern = replace) :
  reiniciando promessa interrompida de avaliação
2: In stringr::str_replace_all(str = string, pattern = replace) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: If I drop the argument, I have the message above..

Comment: @FabianoPinheirodaSilva I cannot reproduce the error. You should consider reading the errors as they often tell you where the problem is. The error says obviously that there is a problem with the library stringi, so I would simply try to reinstall it.

Comment: many thanks, @Felix. worked!!

Comment: I found today the script below for more books... it is downloading, but I can't find where the pdfs are being stored.. can somebody help me?

Comment: `library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

list <- "https://towardsdatascience.com/springer-has-released-65-machine-learning-and-data-books-for-free-961f8181f189"
aux <- read_html(list) %>%
  html_node("div") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_split("http://link.springer.com/openurl\\?genre=book&isbn=")
ids <- substr(unlist(aux), 1, 17)[-1]
sapply(ids, function(x) {
  url <- paste0("https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F", x, ".pdf")
  download.file(url, paste0(x, ".pdf"), mode = "wb")
}) `

Comment: @FelixPhl, could you please try this code?

Comment: @FabianoPinheirodaSilva probably in your working directory?

Comment: yes, it was hidden in my wd, the window was too small.. thanks for that!